# How to read version number (config.xml file) from ios phonegap App?

Tags: cordova

i want to check version update through my IOS Phonegap App. Is there any possible way to get current App version code. please help me to read this version code from config.xml file.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to the party, but I wasn't satisfied with any of the answers/plugins (I wanted to do this without a plugin). If Cordova has a way to get the version via the cordova.* api, then I haven't seen that documentation anywhere, so I came up with another method.

Before building the app, I auto-generate the file `www/version.js` and include it in my app's index.html:

```
cat config.xml \
    | grep '^<widget' \
    | sed -E 's|^.*version="([^"]+)".*|var cordova_app_version = "\1";|' \
    > www/version.js
```

You can then access your app's version via the global variable `cordova_app_version`.

Note that I do this in my project's Makefile, which controls all the building/running so this step is automated each time I do a build. Obviously you'll need a make/bash setup with cat/grep/sed.

Comment: I'm glad you came to the party, much better answer for my needs too. I had to use the following on OSX though, either `sed 's|^.*version="\([^"]*\)".*|var cordova_app_version = "\1";|'` or `sed -E 's|^.*version="([^"]+)".*|var cordova_app_version = "\1";|'`

Comment: Ah, right. I always forget `sed` on OSx is a bit different. Thanks for the translation =]

Comment: It would be great if you edited-in the OSX version in the answer.

Comment: Done. Done. Done.

Comment: Love this party. However it's a toss-up for me. If you use @andrew 's great solution you not only get to see the version number in Cordova, you can also see it in a web browser, which is ace for testing. But it's still a bit of a hack that you'll have to document to remember how, why and wherefore you used it and how it works. If you want to do it the normal way I could only find one plugin which worked - which it does by doing something very similar to this solution - but it only works in Cordova, not in a browser - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova_app_version_plugin

Comment: @mwarren I tend to agree. My projects are all Makefile-heavy, so it's expected to be part of the build system. I'd reccomend my method if you're already using make (or even another build system) that manages cordova. For projects not using a build system (just using `cordova run ...` directly) the plugin route is definitely a great approach.

Answer (score 1):

you can use navigator plugin to get the version number, the version number in config.xml gets added to your manifest/plist.

navigator.appInfo.getVersion();

Comment: what navigator plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the version number in the project .plist (you'll have to increment this anyway in order to upload new versions of the app to iTunes Connect), you can read this version number easily using [this Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizUtils) by calling `window.wizUtils.getBundleVersion()`

Comment: Is there also a solution without a plugin which is unfortunately not available for many platforms? Except for Android and iOS I am looking for a browser version.